# LED problem with recessed lighting

Tags: lighting

My recessed lighting is set up for PAR 20 incandescent bulbs. I would like to switch to LEDs, but the ones I am finding are 1/2" longer than my PAR 20 bulbs. These protrude from the recessed light and will not allow my trim ring to seat. What's up with that?

Comment: Nature of the beast. The LED lamps need a power supply; that takes some space. The power supply needs some heat-sink surface area; that takes some space. It takes **much less** space than it used to, but it means we can't yet make an LED bulb that runs on house current as small as bulbs that use house current directly to heat a filament. Wait another few years and hope, or replace the fixtures...

Comment: Check to see if your fixtures have any adjustment on the socket position - some don't, some do. Often a thumbscrew and a section that slides.

Answer (score 2):

There are [LED replacement kits](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-5-in-and-6-in-White-Recessed-LED-Trim-90-CRI-2700K-CER6730AWH27/204726945) that include a bulb, power supply, and trim ring (if you are not wed to your existing ones). They may be less deep than the bulbs you are finding. The bulb base is separate from the rest of the unit to reduce space and ease installation.

[image: led trim kit]

```
Images and links are for illustration only, not an endorsement of any product or source.
```

Comment: I actually just purchased these retrofits. They work perfectly for your problem!